# axis.ConfigurationException: SAXException: Fatal Error: URI=null Line=56: XML document structures must start and end

Tags: java, tomcat, axis

The problem I am facing is with AXIS 1.2 running on Tomcat. It appears in the log files whenever Tomcat is started.

The error message is a bit mysterious, as it does not point to any particular file.

```
    org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Fatal Error: URI=null Line=56: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    org.xml.sax.SAXException: Fatal Error: URI=null Line=56: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:281)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.newDocument(XMLUtils.java:369)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.newDocument(XMLUtils.java:388)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
```

Answer (score 0):

I took me some time to figure out what is wrong with the setup. In case you came here having no clue what `URI=null` is, let me share this hint with you.

In my case, axis' configuration is here: `~/tomcat/webapps/axis/WEB-INF`. There are two files: `web.xml` (which was the main suspect - an xml file, right? But finally was innocent) and the not-so-obvious culprit:

`server-config.wsdd`

The message literally say: the xml file must end with the same tag as it starts with. If you know where to look, it is obvious that this file starts with `<deployment ...` and should be ended with closing `</deployment>`.

If you only know which file is pointed by `URI=null`...